# Java - How to distinct data on LinkedList Collectoin

Tags: java, linked-list

I have already separating a text file by space and other read mark into LinkedList, but there are several data that duplicated. How to remove the duplicated data and how to count how many I encounter the duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

Put data inside HashSet < String >  instead. On each put you can check if it is already there.

Comment: And you don't even have to check. If you try adding a value that's already there, it just won't get added to the set.

Comment: Depends on whether or not ordering is important.